# Argument of type "const char*" is incompatible with parameter of type "Person"

Tags: c++, error-handling, linked-list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Person{
private:
    string name;
    int age, height, weight;
public:
    Person(string name = "empty", int age = 0, int height = 0, int weight = 0) {
        this->name = name;
        this->age = age;
        this->height = height;
        this->weight = weight;
    }
};

class Node {
public:
    Person* data;
    Node* next;
    Node(Person*A) {
        data = A;
        next = nullptr;
    }
};

class LinkedList {
public:
    Node * head;
    LinkedList() {
        head = nullptr;
    }

void InsertAtHead(Person*A) {
    Node* node = new Node(A);
    node->next = head;
    head = node;
}

void Print() {
    Node* temp = head;
    while (temp != nullptr) {
        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
};

int main() {
    LinkedList* list = new LinkedList();

    list->InsertAtHead("Bob", 22, 145, 70);                 list->Print();      //2
```

}

I am getting the error stated in the question. I am very new to C++ and cannot understand why it is throwing this error. The error happens at the line "list->InsertAtHead("Bob", 22, 145, 70);." This does not make sense to me because if I am pointing to Person object in the InsertAtHead function shouldnt it pass the four parameters from the Person class with the Person object? How would I go about fixing this and getting rid of the error?

Comment: The function wants the address-of a `Person`, not a `Person` object.  You are not providing this.  Also -- *I am very new to C++* -- I suggest getting a good C++ book if you're not already reading one.  C++ is not a language that is to be learned by guessing or assuming what the syntax is supposed to mean.

Comment: There are many more problems with this code than just the compile error. But in terms of fixing the error, you need to actually construct an object of type `Person` and then pass a pointer to it to `InsertAtHead`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `LinkedList::InsertAtHead` is:

```
void InsertAtHead(Person*A) { /* ... */ }
```

That means you must give it a pointer to a `Person` object.  You are calling it like this:

```
list->InsertAtHead("Bob", 22, 145, 70);
```

That's giving it a `const char*` and a bunch of integers.  My guess is you want to do this:

```
list->InsertAtHead(new Person("Bob", 22, 145, 70));
```

Of course, you could also do this:

```
Person *p = new Person("Bob", 22, 145, 70);
list->InsertAtHead(p);
```

But this highlights a potential flaw in your design:  who owns the pointer `*p`?  If you call `delete p` from `main`, the `LinkedList` object will have a pointer to garbage hanging around in it.  If you call `delete A` in `LinkedList::InsertAtHead`, now `main` has a pointer to garbage.  This is not to mention all the problems `Node` might have with a garbage pointer, and all the ways it could pull the rug out from under both `LinkedList` and `main`!

Unless you really need raw pointers for some crazy optimizations, I highly recommend you read up on [resource acquisition is initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) and take it to heart--it's a little more tedious than using raw pointers, but it will save you a lot of headaches down the road.

Comment: Thank you yeah, my professor always used raw pointers so I was completely new to them. I came from Java so things were quite a bit different although similar which makes it confusing as hell

Answer (score 0):

The `InsertAtHead` function takes one parameter of type `Person*`. You are passing it four parameters. Instead, pass it a pointer to a `Person`.

You really shouldn't use naked pointers this way though. It makes it extremely difficulty to manage the lifetime of the objects pointed to. Your `InsertAtHead` function takes a pointer to an existing `Person` object and stores it. That pointer becomes invalid if that `Person` object is ever destroyed. This is just asking for trouble.